# how to swap an element with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following setup within my HTML document...

```
<div id="logo"><h2>my top logo</h2></div>
<div id="one"><p>this is the first section with stuff in it</p></div>
<div id="two"><h1>this is the section section with stuff in it</h1></div>
<script>//this script associates to stuff in div id=two</script>
```

Is there a way to tell < div id = one >, to go under the < script > tag this way it looks like this...

```
<div id="logo"><h2>my top logo</h2></div>
<div id="two"><h1>this is the section section with stuff in it</h1></div>
<script>//this script associates to stuff in div id=two</script>
<div id="one"><p>this is the first section with stuff in it</p></div>
```

I can't depend on a parent div element id that contains all these.  I need to only depend on what you see right here.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this, though I don't know what the purpose of doing this is. It shouldn't change anything about the layout of the page.

```
$("#one").insertAfter( $("#one").nextAll("script").eq(0) );
```

you should fix the html above, you have unopened p tags and unclosed h1 tags.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('#two').next().after($('#one'))
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KANh2/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#two').next('script').after( $('#one') );
```

Comment: `.next('script')` will select exactly 0 elements with the given html

Comment: It won't work, you are inserting `#one` string not the element with ID of `one`.

Comment: @kevin yeah, didn't look closely enough at HTML thanks. undefined I thought selectors worked there for some reason...must have been mis-remembering, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to move them about

`jQuery("#one").after(jQuery("#two"));`

You can also use

`jQuery("#two").before(jQuery("#one"));`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
$("#one").insertAfter($('script'));
```

Given that is the only script tag in your code.  You could implement further checks and balances to make sure it sits directly after the script tags you require.

Comment: Its not the only script tag :( crap!